# Which path information vs fringe visibility can be explained by Heisenberg principle?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, interferometry

the fact that in interferrometry, the which path information deletes the fringe visibility reminds me the Heisenberg  principle, but how to derive this relation?

Answer (score 1):

The Heisenberg uncertainty relation can be stated as

$$\Delta E\Delta t\ge\frac{\hbar}{2},$$

where $\Delta E$ is the uncertainty in energy and $\Delta t$ the uncertainty in time. If we assume to know the experienced energy difference between the two paths $E=\hbar\omega$, then the uncertainty in phase and energy is expressed as $\Delta\theta=\omega\Delta t$ and $\Delta E=\hbar\omega\Delta J_z$, respectively, and where $\Delta J_z$ is the occupation uncertainty between the two interferometer arms. This makes the first equation

$$\Delta \theta\Delta J_z\ge\frac{1}{2}.$$

If we make a measurement after the first beam splitter we gain which path information and so minimise $\Delta J_z$, which in-turn maximises $\Delta\theta$, scrambling the phase information and reducing the fringe visibility.

Comment: Did you find this in a book or is if from you? it is interesting.

Comment: @Naima I did not get it from a book, although, I'm sure similar arguments have been given elsewhere. If you want to know more about the $J_z$ operator there is a good article called `SU(2) and SU(1,1) interferometers' by Bernard Yurke.